# Redirect PHP query

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect visiters from:

```
/plug/survey/survey.php?22
```

to

```
/publications.php?1.articles.view.547
```

I have a limited understanding of .htaccess and php and wonder if anyone has any tips/ideas for me?
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: Are you using Apache?  Read about [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)? What have you tried?

Comment: Then you should read about ;) and learn.

Comment: .htaccess won't work because both links have nothing in common, you must do it with PHP or other server side language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the top of survey.php:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == "22") {
   header("Location: http://example.com/publications.php?1.articles.view.547");
   exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this code in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect /plug/survey/survey.php?22 /publications.php?1.articles.view.547
```

Also read this

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php

Comment: For redirecting users you should use(add) `R` flag

Comment: Thank you very much, but putting this in .htaccess gives me a 500 internal server error. Is there anything I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if it is just the one file, you can use header('Location: '.$url); at the top of the php - see http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Your question really lacks vital information:

Where does that "1.articles" come from - is it a fixed string ?
where dies that "547" come from, I guess it is from a database lookup somehow ?

If so, there is no easy way to do that using plain rewrite rules. 
Most likely the best solution is to write a small php script you redirect to. Inside that script you evaluate the request parameters (php variables $_SERVER and so on), make you database lookup and use the information gathered to send a redirect header to the browser (using phps 'header()' method).

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is

```
header("location:/publications.php?1.articles.view.547");
```

You can use .httaccess, but if you want the user should go on that page you cant use it because it will redirect you before reading any code on that page, but `header()` will first read the code and if any code is something not good then redirect like this,

```
if($varisgood){
   // not redirect
}
else{
   //redirect
}
```